# Problem in AWS Tutorial: Build a Basic Web Application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have completed the tutorial [AWS - Build a Basic Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-web-app-s3-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb/), multiple times, and I am getting the same error on the very last step. When I 'test the updated web app' by entering a First Name, Last Name, then clicking 'Call API', I get the following pop-up:

[image]

The First Name and Last Name are appearing in the DynamoDB table as an item, with the correct timestamp, so part of the call to the API appears to be working. However the message 'Hello from Lambda' followed by the text I filled in is not appearing in the browser.

I am new to this discipline so would welcome a solution! Why am I getting this pop-up and not the desired output?

The html file containing much of the functionality is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <!-- Add some CSS to change client UI -->
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #232F3E;
        }
    label, button {
        color: #FF9900;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        }
     input {
        color: #232F3E;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        // define the callAPI function that takes a first name and last name as parameters
        var callAPI = (firstName,lastName)=>{
            // instantiate a headers object
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            // add content type header to object
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // using built in JSON utility package turn object to string and store in a variable
            var raw = JSON.stringify({"firstName":firstName,"lastName":lastName});
            // create a JSON object with parameters for API call and store in a variable
            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: raw,
                redirect: 'follow'
            };
            // make API call with parameters and use promises to get response
            fetch("https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => alert(JSON.parse(result).message))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>First Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName">
        <label>Last Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName">
        <!-- set button onClick method to call function we defined passing input values as parameters -->
        <button type="button" onclick="callAPI(document.getElementById('fName').value,document.getElementById('lName').value)">Call API</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you send a console.log of your result?
`.then((result) => {console.log("result", result); alert(JSON.parse(result).message)})`

Comment: Okay, I replaced the line `.then(result => alert(JSON.parse(result).message))` with the above and re-deployed in AWS Amplify. Is this what you suggest? On testing in the browser, the problem persists however when I open the Console panel to view logged messages in Chrome I see three messages: _DevTools failed to load source map..._ ; _GET https://dev...amplifyapp.com/favicon.ico 403_ and _result {"statusCode": 200, "body": "\"Hello from Lambda, Ada Lovelace\""}_. This last message is the one that should be displaying on the web page.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I needed you to do.
The `{"statusCode": 200, "body": "\"Hello from Lambda, Ada Lovelace\""}` is the object you retrieved from the server using the API call. As you can see it only contains the keys `statusCode` and `body`. You are however referring to the key `message`(which doesn't exist). Try to use the `body` key instead of `message`. This can be achieved by changing `.message` to `.body` in your alert function.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Expected text is now appearing in the pop-up. I notice now that at the end of my AWS Lambda function I have `return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda, ' + name)
    }` i.e. no reference to a `message` key so I am not really sure how the Amazon tutorial was ever going to work.